# Generate HTML using grape API in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, grape-api

I have a requirement where I need to generate/spit out HTML markup from one of my APIs. I am using grape API but cannot find a way to throw out HTML markup. I can specify content-type as text/html and create a HTML markup but is there a better way to achieve this  like rendering a template similar to below:

```
render template:'my_template' locals: {:data => data}
```

and 'my_template' (HTML) can take care of how the page looks like ? render is an undefined method in GrapeAPI so not sure what other stuff I can use ?

Answer (score 2):

I think it's quite a bad idea to use an API only framework to render HTML...

Nevertheless, you should be able to use the `:txt` content-type to simply render out your string like you described.

You could use ERB for that, as it is part of the standard-library and pretty easy to use:

```
require "erb"

class Template
  attr_reader :name, :data

  def initialize(name, data)
    @name = name
    @data = data
  end

  def build
    raw = File.read("templates/#{name}.erb")
    ERB.new(raw).result(binding)
  end
end
```

as far as I read, grape automatically uses the `to_s` method of an entity to render `:txt`, so you could implement something like this in your model:

```
def to_s
  Template.new(self.class.to_s.downcase, self)
end
```

it might also be possible to register a html content type and write some kind of formatter that does this kind of stuff.